# Which headers should a proxy send? X-Forwarded-Host vs X-Host

Tags: http, header, proxy

Which headers should a proxy send? There seems 2 different headers for forwarding the original host. `X-Forwarded-Host` and `X-Host`. Which of this both headers should a proxy send? Or both headers?

Answer (score 1):

**X-Forwarded-Host** with the caveat that this is not a well defined standard.

Answer (score -2):

Definitely [**X-Forwarded-For**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-forwarded-for). It's what Squid, mod_proxy, et al. use

Comment: X-Forwarded-For serves a completely different purpose.